# Is it possible to remove existing PagingFilter and add new one in same query

Tags: 2011, broker

For some requirement I need to write code something like below and not sure how it is possible -

```cs
Query query = new Query();         
query.setCriteria(completeCriteria);

query.setResultFilter(new PagingFilter(minitems,pageSize));

String [] totalComURIs = query.executeQuery();  

/* Here I want to Remove the exiting PagingFilter and execute the same query with 
   new PagingFilter as below- again */    
query.setResultFilter(new PagingFilter(minitems,(pageSize +5)));

/* This  increment of 5 is not fix and getting calculated with the help of some 
   code after executing query with first PagingFilter */
String [] AllitemURIs = query.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Did you try to executeQuery() then setResultFilter() and executeQuery() again? Does it work? You can only have one result filter so probably calling setResultFilter() the second time will 'overwrite' the result filter.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that setting the result filter again would reset it, so if you would call:

```
query.setResultFilter(myUpdatedPagingFilter);
String [] AllitemURIs = query.executeQuery();
```

that should work (but I am guessing here, I didn't test it).

If it doesn't then you can always revert to creating a new Query object:

```
query = new Query();         
query.setCriteria(completeCriteria);  
query.setResultFilter(myUpdatedPagingFilter);
String [] AllitemURIs = query.executeQuery();
```

That surely should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to have a nice method to handle different filters.

### Example:

```
// Calling method
String[] totalComURIs = ExecuteQuery(criteria, new PagingFilter(currentPosition, pageSize));
String[] AllitemURIs = ExecuteQuery(criteria, new PagingFilter(currentPosition, pageSize+5));

// Method returns String Array
public String[] ExecuteQuery(Criteria criteria, ResultFilter resultFilter)
{
    Query query = new Query();
    query.setCriteria(criteria);
    query.setResultFilter(resultFilter);
    return query.executeQuery();
}
```